# Get all related recipes, without where-filtering

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

This is my Class:

```
public class Recipe
{
        /// <summary>
        /// PK
        /// </summary> 
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        // here should be the Id, for the initial (, in its related) recipes
        public Guid BaseId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// All related recipes
        /// </summary>
        public virtual ICollection<Recipe> RelatedRecipes { get; set; }

        //...
}
```

Actually I want to get all `RelatedRecipes` with a single statement, without extra `Where(x=>...`-filtering.

This is my Context:

`return await context.Recipes.Include(b => b.RelatedRecipes)...`

What should I do ?

Comment: What about using "Select"?

Comment: Whats your expectation and whats your problem. Assuming that You need to use `ToList()` to materialize the query

Comment: @Eldho you mean like using `return await context.Recipes.Include(b => b.RelatedRecipes).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();`, I did. I am not quite sure, why he does not get the `RelatedRecipes`. Is it because of `DataAnnotations` I am missing or because `RelatedRecipes` is a subclass with the same type ? This is how the database, looks like :https://ibb.co/qJkhMhR

Comment: Can you try without asnotracking

Comment: It should be ‘var data = await db.recipes.include(yourentity).ToListAsync()’

Comment: No, this doen't work. This is the return typ of my method(repository) `async Task<IEnumerable<Recipe>>`, when I call the context

Comment: This is for testing it works. You can still return data from your method as its task<ienumerable<receipe>>. Just for debug purpose whether.

Comment: I tried without `AsNoTracking()`, it does not work. I thinks my model is incomplete, because there is no connection between `RelatedRecipes`, `Id`, and `BaseId`(should contain the the `Id` of `RelatedRecipes`, when I create a new related `Recipe`) ?

Comment: Did you use EF Core in asp.net core?I could work well by using:`public async Task<IEnumerable<Recipe>> Index(){var data =await _context.Recipe.ToListAsync();}`

Comment: Be sure that you have added data of `RelatedRecipes` in your database.

Comment: I tried something like this ` Include(r => r.RelatedRecipes.Where(reR => reR.BaseId == r.Id).Select(x => x))`. => "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.", or that `Include(r => r.RelatedRecipes.Select(reR => reR.BaseId == r.Id))` => invalid lambda expression. It doesn't work, what's wrong here, I mean how should it be better ?

Answer (score 0):

If BaseId is for a recipe to point at it's parent recipe, then it would need to be Nullable given there would need to be at least one top level recipe that has no parent.

From there you can configure the relationship between recipes:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Recipe BaseRecipe { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> RelatedRecipes { get; set; } = new List<Recipe>();
}
```

For EF6

```
public class RecipeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Recipe>
{
    public RecipeConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Recipes");
        HasKey(x => x.Id)
            .Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasOptional(x => x.BaseRecipe)
            .WithMany(x => x.RelatedRecipes)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("BaseId"));
    }
}
```

This example does not include a BaseId defined in the entity. You can map FKs in your entities, but this leaves you with 2 sources of truth. (BaseId vs BaseRecipe.Id) Navigation properties (BaseRecipe) are more flexible, and When using navigation properties you can avoid bugs by using Map to resolve FK without properties. (Or shadow properties in EF Core)

To get a recipe and it's related recipes:

```
var recipe = context.Recipes.Include(x => x.BaseRecipe).Include(x => x.RelatedRecipes)
    .Single(x => x.Id == recipeId);
```

The important caveat here is that you should *not* ever attempt to serialize an entity like this, such as returning it from a controller to a view. By default as a serializer will touch every property on an entity which would result in lazy load queries getting kicked off for the base recipe and related recipes, plus each over their base and related recipes. The serializer will abandon an object graph when it encounters self-referencing entities which means either an exception or #null references.

Entity structures should also always reflect the true data state behind the application. You cannot "filter" related entities when loading them such as trying something like:

```
var recipe = context.Recipes.Include(x => x.BaseRecipe).Include(x => x.RelatedRecipes.Where(r => r.IsActive))
    .Single(x => x.Id == recipeId);
```

For instance to only load "active" related recipes or the like. The above isn't allowed. RelatedRecipes will always reflect the complete set of recipes that are related to the retrieved data.

When passing a structure like this to a view, or to filter data, use `Select` to populate a simple view model structure for the data your view will need. This way you can filter the data down to just what the view needs, and pass the relevant IDs back for when you need to load the complete entity state later to make changes.

For instance to get a recipe and it's active related ones to pass to a view:

```
var recipe = context.Recipes
    .Select(x => new RecipeViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        RelatedRecipes = x.RelatedRecipes
             .Where(r => r.IsActive)
             .Select(r => new RecipeViewModel
             {
                 Id = r.Id,
                 Name = r.Name
             }).ToList()
    }).Single(x => x.Id == recipeId);
```

This builds a query to retrieve just the data your view will need to display, down to just one level of active related recipes. The serializer can convert this to JSON etc. without worrying about tripping up on cyclic entity references or tripping extra queries for lazy loads. Note that when using `Select` you do not need to use `Include` for any of the related details. EF will work these out based on the query. `Include` is only needed when loading complete entities, such as when you later want to load an entity to apply updates.

Edit: The BaseRecipe reference is not required, but useful to determine if a recipe has a base, and which it applies to. Without the BaseRecipe reference, the Base ID would likely be needed to differentiate whether a recipe had a base or not:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? BaseId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> RelatedRecipes { get; set; } = new List<Recipe>();
}

public class RecipeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Recipe>
{
    public RecipeConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Recipes");
        HasKey(x => x.Id)
            .Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasMany(x => x.RelatedRecipes)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.BaseId);
    }
}
```

Whether a selected recipe has a base or not would be based on `x.BaseId.HasValue` in this case.

Comment: Why is the extra property `public virtual Recipe BaseRecipe { get; set; }` needed ?

Comment: It isn't needed, it can be useful to get information about the parent recipe. I've expanded the answer to show a mapping without it.